# Inheriting styles from an existing class

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to design an web page in wordpress. I had a existing class called `.current_page_item a {}` which is used to highlight the selected menu, I need to add this effect to my menu with id **#menu-projects-menu** and need to change the font color. When I write `.current_page_item a {
    color: yellow !important;
    border-bottom: yellow solid 1px !important;
}` like this in **header.php** it changes all the anchor tag color in the whole website. Is there any way to change only current page item.
NB: I don't have a pro version to write custom css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achive this by adding your page unique class before the .current_page_item a
like this . you can find it by inspecting the page body tag.

```
.your_current_page_class .current_page_item a {
    color: yellow !important;
    border-bottom: yellow solid 1px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much bro, It worked. Only this   ```border-bottom: yellow solid 1px !important;
```  works the font color is not changing.